# Preventing duplicates in the database 

Tags: php, database

I am making a simple student management system which has four forms. How can I prevent duplicate entries in the database? I want to prevent duplicates, what I should add in ths code?

```
<html>
 <head>
      <title>Student list</title>
          <link href="stylesheets/public.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 </head>
<body id="background">
  <table >
     <tr>
     <td>
     <img src=" images/Picture3.png" width="1300" height="150"/>
 </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
             <table>
             <tr>

 <td id="structure">
 <? 
  $name=$_POST['name']; 
  $email=$_POST['email']; 
  $shift=$_POST['shift'];
  $class=$_POST['class'];
  $id=$_POST['id'];
  ?><?php



 $var= mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
  mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());



$username = $_POST['name']; // you must escape any input. Remember.

$query = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `$name` = '{name}'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if ( mysql_num_rows ( $result ) > 1 )
{
    /* Username already exists */
    echo 'Username already exists';
}
else
{



  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `data`(name,email,shift,class) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$shift','$class')"); }












  Print "Your information has been successfully added to the database."; 
  ?>
  <?php 
  // Connects to your Database 
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
  mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()); 
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data") 
  or die(mysql_error()); 
  Print "<table border cellpadding=5>"; 
  while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
  {

  Print "<tr>";
  Print "<th>Id:</th><td>".$info['id']."</td>";
  Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['name'] . "</td> "; 
  Print "<th>Email:</th> <td>".$info['email'] . " </td>";
  Print "<th>shift:</th> <td>".$info['shift'] . " </td>";
  Print "<th>class:</th> <td>".$info['class'] . " </td>";
  Print "<tr><td><a href='update.php?id={$info['id']}'>EDIT</a></td></tr>";
  PRINT "<tr><td><a href='delete.php?id={$info['id']}'>DELETE</a></td></tr>";

  } 
  Print "</table>"; 
  ?>
  </td></tr>
  </table>
 </body></html>
```

Comment: A code dump isn't a very useful question. I recommend Googling your question first -- one of the [first results](http://pb.zambale.com/2012/01/25/mysql-prevent-duplicates-using-the-unique-constraint/) is very applicable.

Comment: @dbaseman: BECAUSE IT IS URGENT!!1

Comment: The mysql_* functions have been deprecated as of PHP 5.3, Relying on them is highly discouraged. Consider using either PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I update your code.

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Student list</title>
<link href="stylesheets/public.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body id="background">
<table >
  <tr>
    <td><img src=" images/Picture3.png" width="1300" height="150"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="structure">
    <? 
    // check for post data
    if( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['shift']) && isset($_POST['class']) && isset($_POST['id']) )
    {
        $name=$_POST['name']; 
        $email=$_POST['email']; 
        $shift=$_POST['shift'];
        $class=$_POST['class'];
        $id=$_POST['id'];

        $username = $_POST['name']; // you must escape any input. Remember.

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `name` = '".$username."'";

        $result = mysql_query($query);
        // check for duplicate
        if ( mysql_num_rows ( $result ) > 1 )
        {
            echo 'Username already exists';
        }
        else
        {
            // insert new record
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `data`(name,email,shift,class) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$shift."','".$class."')");  
            print "Your information has been successfully added to the database."; 
        }
    }

    // list data
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data")  or die(mysql_error()); 
    print "<table border cellpadding=5>"; 
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
    {
        print "<tr>";
        print "<th>Id:</th><td>".$info['id']."</td>";
        print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['name'] . "</td> "; 
        print "<th>Email:</th> <td>".$info['email'] . " </td>";
        print "<th>shift:</th> <td>".$info['shift'] . " </td>";
        print "<th>class:</th> <td>".$info['class'] . " </td>";
        print "<tr><td><a href='update.php?id={$info['id']}'>EDIT</a></td></tr>";
        print "<tr><td><a href='delete.php?id={$info['id']}'>DELETE</a></td></tr>";
    } 
    print "</table>"; 

  ?>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems you only reformatted the code. What are your contributions?

Comment: What are the specific errors you corrected? Enumerating them would help @FAWAZ and future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your database, you can specify a "unique" constraint for any column.  For an example, see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

Comment: I KNOW ABOUT UNQUE CONTRAINT BUT I WANT TO DO IT BY  THE HELP OF SQL

Comment: @FAWAZ: why would you not want to use unique constraint? Is it because it returns an error if you insert a duplicate record? You can just use a select query to check if a record already exists.

Comment: @FAWAZ, can you not type in all caps? looks like you're yelling at people.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to determine which column of a record should not be duplicated. Like firstName can have duplicates, so can be date of birth. But SSN cannot be duplicate. Or may be based on your business logic set of columns cannot be duplicate like combination of firstname,lastname,dob and fathersName cannot be duplicate.

After deciding this when you create your table in database you have to apply [unique constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Comment: I WANT THAT EMAIL SHOULD NOT BE DUPLCATED

Comment: so suppose the table name is user and it has columns id,firstname,lastname,email it would be created something like this in mysql   CREATE TABLE USER
(
Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Email varchar(100),
UNIQUE (Email)
)

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of displaying only **unique records** then :

```
SELECT DISTINCT (Column1,Column2, ...) FROM Data
```

If you are thinking of modifying table in the way it adds / inserts / consumes only unique records then 
[**unique constraint**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) is fine.

regards.

---X----
*In your code :*

```
$username = $_POST['name']; // you must escape any input. Remember.

$query = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `$name` = '{name}'";
```

you have stored the name in the $username and using $name 
it should :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `name` = '$username'";
```

Comment: i have stored the name in $name not $username

Comment: then for what $username is stands for ? also why you are using { } braces in the Query ?